# Dealing with Java CookieManager "Invalid cookie" errors

Tags: java, http, cookies

I have defined a `CookieStore` as follows:

```
CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager );
cookieManager.setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL);
```

Whenever I complete a request using `HttpURLConnection`:

```
URL url = new URL(MY_URL);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

I get this in my output:

```
java.net.CookieManager put SEVERE: Invalid cookie for https://...: ; HttpOnly
```

How should I deal with this message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first identify what kind of exception is being thrown.  From looking at the documentation for CookieManger: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/net/CookieManager.java.html

```
  283                       try {
  284                           cookies = HttpCookie.parse(headerValue);
  285                       } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  286                           // Bogus header, make an empty list and log the error
  287                           cookies = java.util.Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
  288                           if (logger.isLoggable(PlatformLogger.SEVERE)) {
  289                               logger.severe("Invalid cookie for " + uri + ": " + headerValue);
  290                           }
  291                       }
```

It seems that the issue is that your headers for your request is incorrect.  Might want to look into that and here is a link of example code.

http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=java.net.CookieManager

Also you probably want to use the chrome debugger to see the actual request being sent out and usually it will give you more information on why the request failed.  The request could be incorrect, the url you are trying to send it to could be invalid, the service that your sending the request to might expect certain parameters.

From the code, it seems to look for the headers in the response.  However, the response itself either contains no headers or there is something wrong with it and as a result HttpCookie.parse will throw a error.

If you look at HttpCookies.parse it throws an exception if:

Throws:

```
IllegalArgumentException - if header string violates the cookie specification's syntax, or the cookie name contains llegal characters, or the cookie name is one of the tokens reserved for use by the cookie protocol
NullPointerException - if the header string is null
```

So you need to look at the response and see if the data they put in the header is correct.